# connectivity Error, How to minimize it. I use share-hosting for my web

Tags: php, ajax, connectivity

I find google bots cannot reach my web. In google webmaster tools, it said **Truncated Response**. I try to find reference in google about this but no other alternatives way to handle it. Then I try use ajax to load my part of web (content.php). I found this script in w3school:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","content.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
});
</script>
```

content.php contains to display article from database.
I dont have some $ to buy dedicated server. please let me know how to minimize if you have other method.

Comment: Why do you think that an ajax call done by the client is related to a `Truncated Response` reported by the webmaster tools? The `Truncated Response` might be a wrong `Content-Length` send by the server.

Comment: No, I mean. my web has error server connectivity (google webmaster tools). Then I try to use ajax if it can solve. But It got failed. I need others method to solve it. I'm trying to fetch but it said: temporarily unreachable

Comment: For the server both, a regular request and an AJAX request is the same, as both are regular HTTP requests. Without observing the connection it is not possible to tell you what what the problem is. As I said `Truncated Response` indicates that your server tells that the response is  X Bytes long but closes the connection before X Bytes are send. This might happen if you set `Content-Length` yourself. Anyway SO is not the right place to ask such a question.